# Поиск элемента в дереве рекурсивным способом

Tags: дерево, бинарное-дерево, c++

Привет всем.

Есть небинарное дерево. Надо сделать функцию поиска элемента в поддереве. Т.е. узнать, в каком поддереве лежит данный элемент: в левом или в правом. Вот функция обхода (симметрический, рекурсивный).

```
int Obxod(ElemT * pCur, int a)
{
    if (pCur != NULL) {
    if (pCur->pRight != NULL)
        Obxod(pCur->pRight, a);
    if (pCur->Sod == a)
        return 1;
    if (pCur->pLeft != NULL)
        Obxod(pCur->pLeft, a);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Помогите найти баг. Почему функция не возвращает 1, если она найдет элемент в поддереве. А всегда в любом случае возвращает -1. Т.е. она вообще не заходит в тело условного оператора/ Проверял на NULL указатели главного ключа на left/right - все в норме. 
Вот как вызывается эта функция для поддерево. В функцию передается указатель на поддерево и значение, которое надо найти.

```
cout << "nЛевое поддерево = " << Obxod(pHead->pLeft, ii);
cout << "nПравое поддерево = " << Obxod(pHead->pRight, ii);
```

Comment: Как исправить ситуацию.. С Левым поддеревом дружит. А вот у правого поддерева она не видит элементы правого узла.. Т.е. правого поддерева, правое поддерево т.е. подподдерева)))))

Comment: Спасибо Владимир что уделили время, для меня :-) Все теперь точно все работает прогнал через тест. Результаты правильные. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд: т.к. функция рекуррентная, то необходимо обрабатывать результат каждого ее вызова, чтобы знать, когда остановиться. Пример (измененный вариант, чтобы легче читать):

```
int Obxod (ElemT* pCur, int a)
{
  if(pCur==NULL)
    return -1;

  if(pCur->Sod == a)
    return 1;

  int local_res(-1);
  if(pCur->pRight!=NULL)
    local_res = Obxod(pCur->pRight,a); 
  if(local_res < 0 && pCur->pLeft!=NULL)
    local_res = Obxod(pCur->pLeft,a);

  return local_res;
}
```

Comment: Все большое спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: Извините.Но исправленная функция не всегда тоже находит.

Comment: Сущ. элемент но он возвращает все равно -1.

Comment: Да, думаю, дело вот в чем. не хватает возврата из функции, если в правом поддереве обнаружен нужный элемент:
`if(pCur->pRight!=NULL)
   local_res = Obxod(pCur->pRight,a);
 else if (local_res>0)
   return 1;`

Comment: Сейчас вообще не находит элементы!? Ни в левом и ни в правом!

Comment: Я изменил вид функции в ответе - так должно лучше читаться и правильно работать. Если все же проблемы останутся, то надо в отладчике по-шагово разбираться, что именно работает не так.